# C# object initializers - Include the constructor call parentheses?

Tags: c#, object

I am a new C# developer.

I have a Class Employee

IS there a difference when declaring an object with and without "**()**". Visual Studio does not flag an error
. For example

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee() { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

or

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

Comment: No, there is no difference. It is not an error, so VS does not mark it as one.

Comment: No difference except for readability.  I find the first variant slightly more readable, as it is a reminder that the parameterless constructor is being called.

Comment: Note that Microsoft [appears to favor omitting the parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) if the parameterless constructor is being called (you can "mix and match" parameterized constructors and object initialization).

Comment: `new Employee()` `new Employee {}` and `new Employee() {}` are all equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference in the code samples you've got there. The parentheses are totally optional.

Differences would arise in a couple of variations, though:

First, if your Employee class had a non-default constructor that you want to provide parameters to, you can't omit the parentheses while still passing arguments to the constructor.

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee(employeeId) { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

Second: the next version of C# (9), where type targeting has been improved, so you won't need to include the name of the class if you already declared what type you're creating:

```
Employee newEmployee = new() { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

Omitting the parentheses in that case would make the compiler think you're trying to create an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses and stuff inside the "()" is called a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). It's fine to instantiate the object with out the parentheses if your class does not require any parameters. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) it provides multiple examples of how to instantiate an object with and without parentheses.

Hope you're enjoying C#

Comment: @mjwills Updated - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not passing any parameters to the constructor, then you can skip opening and closing brackets.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

```cs
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
Cat sameCat = new Cat("Fluffy"){ Age = 10 };
```

Class `Cat` has overloaded constructor so you can pass `Name` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

These are the object initializers anonymously. There are two scenarios:

- When have to pass something in constructor then must have to use `()` brackets.

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee("David") { LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

- When not have to pass something in constructor then its optional to use `()` brackets or not.

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
Employee newEmployee = new Employee() { FirstName = "David", LastName = "HasselHoff", Email_ID ="dh@fdh.com" };
```

These both are same.